# How to get entire values from database using GroupBy Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are having 10 Counts in `MenuMaster` By using `Groupby` I am able to get `ModuleName` of MenuMaster. How to get `Icon Name` And `ClassName` based On `ModuleName` Below i have attached Image For your Reference, Where I am getting ModuleName Only and unable to get Remaining Values.

How to get Remaining values from MenuMaster?

```
<ul class="side-menu-list">
    <li class="grey with-sub">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="lbl">
            Dashboard
            <span class="font-icon font-icon-dashboard lbl"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    @if (Session["MenuMaster"] != null)
    {
        var MenuMaster = (List<MedOrbits_MVC.Models.UserModules>)Session["MenuMaster"];
        var groupByMenu = MenuMaster.GroupBy(x => x.ModuleName).ToList();

        foreach (var MenuList in groupByMenu)
        {
            <li class="purple with-sub">
                <span>
                    <i class="font-icon font-icon-build"></i>
                    <span class="lbl">@MenuList.Key</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

[image]

[image: 10Counts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group by the three attributs :

```
<ul class="side-menu-list">
    <li class="grey with-sub">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="lbl">
            Dashboard
            <span class="font-icon font-icon-dashboard lbl"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    @if (Session["MenuMaster"] != null)
    {
        var MenuMaster = (List<MedOrbits_MVC.Models.UserModules>)Session["MenuMaster"];
        var groupByMenu = MenuMaster.GroupBy(x => new{ x.ModuleName, x.ClassName, x.IconName}).ToList();

        foreach (var MenuList in groupByMenu)
        {
            <li class="purple with-sub">
                <span>
                    <i class="@MenuList.Key.IconName"></i>
                    <span class="@MenuList.Key.ClassName">@MenuList.Key.ModuleName</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```